# capturing form response in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form in html page, I tried to use AJAX to capture the response but somehow I did not send the request to the server. Where am I wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(function() {  
  $(".button").click(function() {  
  var clin=$("input#client").val();
  var us=$("input#username").val();
  var dataString='client='+clin+'&username='+us;
    $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "http://localhost:8080/services/web?wsdl/authen",  
          data: dataString,  
          success: function(response) {  
            alert("The server says: " + response);
          }  
        });  
            return false;   
  });  
});  
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="myform">
        <form name="frm1">
            <table>
                Enter Your User Account:
                <tr>
                    <td>Client ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text-input" type="text" size="30" name="client" id="client">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>User ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text-input" type="text" size="30" name="username" id="username">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="get" class="button" id="submit_btn">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to capture the form response in AJAX but not sure if I did was correct?
I provide my server web services:

```
      xs:element name="authen"> <br>
         xs:complexType> <br>
             xs:sequence> <br>
                 xs:element name="ClientID" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/> <br>
                 xs:element name="UserID" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/> <br>
             /xs:sequence><br>
         /xs:complexType><br>
    /xs:element><br>
    xs:element name="authenResponse"><br>
         xs:complexType><br>
             xs:sequence><br>
                 xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/><br>
             xs:sequence><br>
         xs:complexType><br>
    xs:element><br>
```

Comment: You submit the form manually, which redirects the page.

Comment: As per xdazz's instructions you did change the `frm1`. Now Is it working?

Comment: Just for confirmation, Have you added jQuery library file?

Comment: yes i followed xdazz's instruction but not working. and yes I added jQuery library. I'm using eclipse by the way.

Comment: Open up the network tab in your inspect of choice (you'll have to enable AJAX logging in the Chrome inspector). Does it ever request the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added jQuery source file then ignore this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add a script tag like this just after starting of `<head>` tag.

You should have to download and place a jQuery file to your appropriate folder structure.

Here is the Latest version of [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js)

Comment: no error. so when I click the button, there is no connection to my server.

Comment: I tried and It can call the server. I miss a colon somewhere. Thanks! But, my server response with a blank page, it should response with some value. How can I display the value out?

Comment: Add `dataType: "xml",` with other parameters and write `console.log(response);` in `success` and check

Comment: i got this error:

Servlet.service() for servlet [AxisServlet] in context with path [/services] threw exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

means my pass in value was wrong?

Comment: There could be somthing wrong in your `service()` with the parameter you passed.

Comment: i not sure if the passing in the value was right, initially i used <form action="http://...." method="post"> when i does the request to my server, it ok and return with XML response. Now if i use AJAX, is ('client='+clin+'&username='+us) the right way to post to the server?

Comment: Do like this `var dataString="client='"+clin+"'&username='"+us;` Means wrap values in String when passing as a Query String

Comment: i change using just double quote, things was send to server. But the response is blank. console.log(response) did not print anything?

Comment: Ok. So Does it means that now Request is going to Server?

Comment: yes the request is send to server, but the server reply was not capture by the function(response), response is null.

Comment: So now you have to trace individually in that your Server file (means of dynamic file which sends output). Debug there with some static values and check whether it's generating any output or not with those static values.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below line:

```
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
```

You are using ajax, so you don't need to submit the form using `submit()`.
Besides, there is no form whose id is `frm1`, so the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null` will happen and stop your script.

Comment: I removed the above tag as you said, but it is still the same, there no communication to my server